# From a set of conditions on variable X producing values Y, how to generate a closed-form formula $Y=f(X)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I'm very poor at math, and basically what is interesting me into it is a game.

I'm trying to figure out a function (I guess it is a function) where X is a variable number that goes from 1 to 200.

And Y should be a value depending on X.
There is another variable (a constant) that has a fixed value: 48.
Where I'm facing a difficulty is how to define $Y$.

- Each value of X gives me 3 additional points when X is between 2 and 5;
- when X value is between 6 and 10, each additional point gives me 4 points;
- when X value is between 10 and 15, each additional points gives me 5 points. This goes on and on until X = 200.

So, basically, every additional point of X increases the value of Y, and depending on the value of X it will increase the value of Y by 1 at every 5 points.

So, if X = 16, Y = 48 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 6 = 111.
Where 48 is a constant, the additional values of 3 is based when X is between 2 and 5, the additional values of 4 is based when X is between 6 and 10, and so on.

What I'm looking for is a function returning the total value that X has given.

Sorry for my broken english, hope that I make myself understandable.

Comment: What happens if $X=1$? Should $Y$ just be $48$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'm going to assume that when $X=1$, then $Y=48$.

Then the formula should be:

$$Y=\frac{5k\left(k+1\right)}{2}+q\left(k+1\right)+30$$
where $k=\left\lfloor\frac X5\right\rfloor+2$ and $q\equiv X\pmod5$ with $0\le q\le4$.

If $X=16$, then $k=\left\lfloor\frac{16}5\right\rfloor+2=5$ and $q\equiv16\pmod5$ with $0\le q\le4\implies q=1$. Then the formula gives:

$$Y=\frac{5\cdot5\left(5+1\right)}{2}+1\cdot(5+1)+30=111$$as expected.

Here is a [Desmos link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/argdfmbguu?nographpaper) which contains the formula specified above.

Comment: @DS You sure you plug in correctly? Check the Desmos link I give in the answer that has the function, it confirms that $X=16$ gives $Y=111$.

Comment: @DS The exact text from question body (bold is my emphasis): "So, if X = 16, Y = 48 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 6 = **111**."

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad

Comment: Thank you very much Sir.

Answer (score 0):

I propose that you don't try and find a "formula". 200 values is not too much, just define a lookup table for each value of $X$. You can use a spreadsheet to calculate the lookup table entries.

Comment: Interesting, but this should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @JeanMarie I wrote this as an answer because I believe it is a more general approach than just: "here is an ad hoc combination of "floor/ciel/mod" that happens to solve your specific problem", and as such worthy to be an answer.